# Marker on Last Data Point of Line Chart

Tags: python, bokeh

How do I place a marker on the last data points of each series in my line chart?

I have tried:

```
last_val = data.loc[df.index.max(), column]

c = Circle(
    x=data.index.max(),
    y=last_val,
    radius=3,
    ...
)

fig.add_glyph(c, y_range_name='my_range')
```

and:

```
from bokeh.util.serialization import convert_datetime_type

last_val = convert_datetime_type(data.loc[df.index.max(), column])

c = Circle(
    x=data.index.max(),
    y=last_val,
    radius=3,
    ...
)

fig.add_glyph(c, y_range_name='my_range')
```

But I do not see any circles. What am I doing wrong?

Please note, my series are plotted against different y-ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

`fig.circle` is the way to go and only give it the last point:

```
fig.circle(
    [data.index.max()], 
    [data.loc[data.index.max(), column]], 
    color=line_colour, size=3, y_range_name=range_name)
```

Comment: For context: `Circle` is a low level glyph model. It only plots data out of an associated data source, you cannot pass data to it directly. `Plot.circle` will take care of setting all that up and is the generally recommended API unless there is a specific reason

Comment: FYI it should just work to pass the single x, y values to `fig.circle` as well.